# PowerShell's Write-Output, echo and output redirection insert excessive characters into output

Tags: windows, powershell, hex

### The story

I'm writing a program that outputs a sequence of hex digits like does `xxd -ps` command.
This output is intended to be converted into a binary file, e.g. with `xxd -ps -r`.
When I try to invoke `xxd -ps -r` on my hex output in PowerShell I don't get the desired binary, xxd's output is empty.

### The problem

After some investigation I've revealed that PowerShell's Write-Output, it's alias echo and output redirection '>' — all they insert excessive characters like '\00' and some others into output.

### The question

How to get rid of this behavior and wean Powershell from corrupting data flows between commands?

### The test

I would like Powershell to behave like the good old cmd:

```
ps>java -cp HelloWorld > hello.txt
ps>xxd -ps hello.txt > hello.hex
ps>xxd -ps -r hello.hex
ps>HelloWorld

ps>
```

Currently the last command has empty output.

### I'm ok

Now I will write my own hex to binary converter in java, which is ok for my project, even better, but I think I will eventually stumble upon this problem in the future so I want to be prepared.

Answer (score 3):

I've found something similar in the past. If the data is binary, redirection produces a corrupted output due to newline characters. I've resolved thanks to this [good article](http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2007/01/18/redirecting-binary-output-in-powershell/).